# erro na criação de subplots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Estou tentado criar varios graficos usando o seguinte procedimento:

```
fig_2, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20, 5))
axes[0].plot(abril.Date_Time, abril.CPUs_pct)
axes[1].plot(abril.Date_time, abril.Mem_pct)
axes[2].plot(abril.Date_time, abril.Swap_pct)
```

o erro que dá é o seguinte:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Peço uma dica em como resolver este problema

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O [`subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) do Python recebe como parâmetros o número de linhas e colunas para desenhar a grade com os gráficos. Pelo seu código, `fig_2, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20, 5))`, a grade terá `4` gráficos em uma grade `2x2`. Para acessar os gráficos, a maneira correta é dizer a linha e a coluna.

```
# axes[linha, coluna]
axes[0,0].plot(abril.Date_Time, abril.CPUs_pct)
```

Este trecho colocaria o gráfico `.plot(abril.Date_Time, abril.CPUs_pct)` na linha `0` e coluna `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Olha eu modifiquei o codigo desta maneira: `fig_2, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20, 5))
axes[0,0].plot(abril.Date_Time, abril.CPUs_pct)
axes[0,1].plot(abril.Date_Time, abril.Mem_pct)
axes[1,0].plot(abril.Date_Time, abril.Swap_pct)
plt.show()`

Mas existe outro erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Ja está resolvido, faltava inserir `%matplotlib inline` no topo.

Obrigado